# Angular 2 - Card translate animations when filter

Tags: angular, animation

Do you know how to make dynamic translations of cards when they are filtered in angular 2? An animation like this bootstrap theme :

http://kingstudio.ro/demos/eyecatcher/index3.html

(Animations of the portfolio at the bottom of the page when you click in a button)

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The only way for me to do this is to play with the property `transform: translate` in CSS.

Let's check the website you linked to your post : it's the element with the class `.shuffle-item` and `.filtered` which moves from a position to another with this property. You have to calculate the new position `x,y` of each element. For example, on the website you provided, each row have 4 elements. If you want the coordinates of the 13 element, `x = 13 % 4 = 1` and `y = 13 / 4 = 3`. You just need to multiply these numbers by the element width and element height